# Group columns and add new aggregated fields using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a dataset like this:

```
car,color,price
Audi,RED,12000
Audi,BLUE,17000,
Audi,BLUE,16000
Seat,BLUE,12500
Fiat,RED,14800
.
.
```

Please note that the color can only have two values (RED and BLUE).

I need to return report dataset:

```
car, totalprice, totalpriceRED, totalPriceBLUE
Audi, 45000, 12000, 33000
Seat, 12500, 0 , 12500
.
```

Grouped by car, but also with added aggregated columns (one for the total amount, and two for the amount by colors). Some car maybe does not some color, so the corresponding total for that color would be 0

I am trying to do this wit LINQ and C#, but I can not find a way to do a grouping like this one. If anyone could help I would be grateful.

Comment: _I am trying to do this wit LINQ and C#_ Please, share what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to [group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) car, then construct a new object that contains the total price, and the total price for each colour, which you can construct with [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1)

```
cars.GroupBy(x => x.car).Select(x => new
 {
 car = x.Key,
 totalprice = x.Sum(y => y.price),
 totalpriceRed = x.Where(y => y.color == "RED").Sum(y => y.price),
 totalpriceBlue = x.Where(y => y.color == "BLUE").Sum(y => y.price)
 });
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NmmUKb